# How to remove/disable width 100% automatically?

Tags: css, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I don't know why the svg tag always gives width 100% style.

I've already comment it, but it still shows me the 100% width.

```
svg {
  /*-webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;*/
  /* Trying to get SVG to act like a greedy block in all browsers */
  display: block;

 /* width:100%;
  height:100%;*/
  width: auto;
  min-width: 0;
 display: table;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why NVD3 authors decided it was kosher to mess with SVG style universally. Among other issues, it breaks other libs like Leaflet (won't show LineString features).

Answer (score 0):

SVG will try to fit the container unless you specify a fixed width. You can use the `viewbox`property to limit that size. Think of SVG as a container or canvas. Then, `viewbox` is the size of the graphic element INSIDE that canvas.

Example code:

```
<svg width="1000" height="400" viewBox="0 0 500 200">
```

in this case, the SVG will have a max width of 1000px, but your images will be half of it.

then, with this in place, you can apply

```
svg{width:100%; height:100%}
```

and voilá, responsive SVG that automatically adjust size to containing element

Comment: It is misleading to say "your images will be half of it".  If you specify a viewBox, the area of the SVG described by the viewBox will be scaled to fit the specified width and height.